# Phonegap Facebook Plugin Login Error: Should not pass a read permission

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, plugins

I'm developing an android mobile application that integrates with Facebook. Using this [Phonegap Facebook Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin) and **CLI**, I followed the tutorial (show HackBook). I currently have this HackBook display to my mobile device. Unfortunately, I'm getting this error in *logcat* when I'm trying to login.

> Should not pass a read permission (email) to a request for publish or
> manage authorization THREAD WARNING: exec() call to
>
> org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect.login blocked the main thread for
> 41ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().

Am I missing something in the Facebook Application? In my Facebook Application Settings,I have two platforms: *App on Facebook* and *Website*.

Can anyone explain to me what is happening or what did I do wrong? Should I have Android Platform too?

Thank you in advance!!!!

Answer (score 5):

[Fixed] After logging in, The screen will display a blank page. It turns out that it cannot connect to my Facebook App. My facebook app setting is not configured correctly. I should make it live and public.

**Facebook App Settings** > **Status And Review** > "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" **Change to Yes**.